# can't fix INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED in my Flutter Apps

Tags: android, flutter, intentfilter

So guys I can't install the apps on my emu. I already search for the solution and try it but it still didn't work

> Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1440002151.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #154): com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]

In the AndroidManifest.xml file I already added android:exported = 'true'

[image]

any suggestion of what should I do or should I re-configure my emu? Here is the full list of xml file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="io.indiflix.pari.widget">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
   <application
        android:label="PARI"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
</manifest>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share what version of flutter_local_notifications are you using? And what is your target sdk version?

Comment: flutter_local_notifications: ^8.1.1+1, where to check target sdk ?

Comment: It will be inside /android/app/build.gradle

Comment: the targeted sdk version is 33 @rrttrr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is not originating from your side, it is from `flutter_local_notifications` package.

This is probably because you are using an older version of that package.

Try upgrading `flutter_local_notifications` to the latest version.

Comment: Ok i will try to update it first